# Update ACF field form field that recovers ID post

Tags: php, wordpress, webforms

**I want to recover the Id from a form to update the hour in a custom field,**

---

The custom field exists already,

I have a form that asks the user the post id in WordPress,

```
  <form id="visitor-out" method="post">
  <label for="vsearchOut">Search visiteur code:</label><be>
  <input type="search" id="vsearchOut" name="vsearchOut"><be>
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenInput" name="accion2" value="vsearchOut">
  <button id="buttonSortir">Sortir</button><be>
  </from>
```

My code to get the id is incomplete

```
if(isset($_POST['accion2']) and $_POST['accion2']=='visitor-out'):
    $post_id =  $_POST['vsearchOut'];
    $args= array(
        'post_type' => 'visitors',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_title'=> $_POST['fname']  
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
    update_field('Visiteurs-date-out',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),$post_id); 
    header('location:'.get_bloginfo('url').'/confirmation');

    exit;  
    endif;
```

Comment: Your form does not contain any field named `accion`, so your if condition will never be true.

Comment: also it does not have any input with name `fname`!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: I was using another code I meant to create a post, so I was having more code than needed just to edit/upload the field.

This is the corrected version:

```
if(isset($_POST['accion2']) and $_POST['accion2']=='visitor-out'):
    $post_id =  $_POST['vsearchOut'];

    update_field('Visiteurs-date-out',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),$post_id); 
    header('location:'.get_bloginfo('url').'/confirmation');

    exit;  
    endif;
```

HTML

````
  <form id="visitor-out" method="post">
  <label for="vsearchOut">Search visiteur code:</label><be>
  <input type="search" id="vsearchOut" name="vsearchOut"><be>
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenInput" name="accion2" value="vsearchOut">
  <button id="buttonSortir">Sortir</button><be>
  </from>
```
````